# Changing "Month Date" to "Year-Month-Date" in R

Tags: r, date, format

In R, I have a vector of the form

```
> date
  [1] "Jan 16"  "Feb 10"  "Dec 11"
```

Now I want to change it to form "Year-Month-Date" form in R with a specific year, say 2011. So the output should be:

```
>date
[1] "2011-01-16" "2011-02-10" "2011-12-11"
```

Could anyone help me to do this in R?

Comment: Try  `as.Date(paste(date, 2011), '%b %d %Y')` or using `library(lubridate); mdy(paste(date, 2011))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also begin to explore the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
date <- c("Jan 16",  "Feb 10",  "Dec 11")

# month, day , year
mdy(paste(date, 2011))

[1] "2011-01-16 UTC" "2011-02-10 UTC" "2011-12-11 UTC"
```

If you don't want the time zone appended you can then use `as.Date`

```
as.Date(mdy(paste(date, 2011)))
[1] "2011-01-16" "2011-02-10" "2011-12-11"
```

With `mdy` you can also specify locale and time zone

```
mdy(paste(date, 2011), locale=Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"), tz="UTC")
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547769) suggested, `as.Date(paste(date, 2011), '%b %d %Y')` may be used for that. The problem starts, however, if your current locale is not an English one but you'd like to parse English abbreviated month names anyway.
For that, you will need to switch your default locale to another one, temporarily. Here is a solution for that:

```
date <- c("Jan 16", "Feb 10", "Dec 11")
oldloc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME") # save current locale
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "POSIX") # switch to an English (US) one
as.Date(paste(date, 2011), '%b %d %Y') # @akrun's solution
## [1] "2011-01-16" "2011-02-10" "2011-12-11"
Sys.setlocale(oldloc) # restore locale
```

Here the `%b` format stands for an abbreviated month name. On the other hand, for full names, use `%B`, see `?strptime`.